# Is there a way i could call a gradle task from within the java program

Tags: android-studio, robotium, android-gradle-plugin

I want the android app that is being tested to be uninstalled everytime a new test method in the class runs. I know that gradle uninstallAll task does this. But i would like to call this task from the setup method of the testcase class.

Comment: You want to (re)install the tested app fresh for each test? This would make running the tests very very slow.

Comment: @xavier-ducrohet Yes. The other alternative i had was to clear the app data so that each test starts from the first screen. I couldnt find any solutions to how to do that.

Comment: The current instrumentation runner won't allow you to do that. You'd have to do that outside of the Android runtime, get the list of tests, and for each test do an install, run the test, uninstall and keep going on the next test.